# Measure Junction capacitence of sensor

Tags: capacitance

I would like to know how can I measure or calculate the junction capacitance of an oxygen sensor(or photodiode or any current source sensor).

The manufacturer does not have this information on their datasheet. 
http://www.teledyne-ai.com/pdf/schem_a59452.pdf

Comment: What if the output node is the output of an opamp? Otherwise, hang a 100Kohm resistor between output of a square-wave generator, amplitude 1voltpp, and the Sensor output. Hang a 10pF (13pF) scope probe on the Sensor output, and measure the timeconstant.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible when The sensor is generating its own current. I will try to draw schematic so we can discuss it.